# How to use meta-programming to add lines if a certain method is called

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to do the following?

Whenever a method is called as the final line within the body of another method, I want the method call to be surrounded by a pair of lines.

The following method:

```
def my_method
    do_some_stuff
    byebug
end
```

should be transformed into:

```
def my_method
    x = do_some_stuff
    byebug
    x
end
```

Comment: Is it for "a certain method" (as the title says), or any method that comes as final (as the body says)? What do you mean by "a pair of lines"?

Comment: To me it sounds like _"Using hammer to drill screws if a certain wall is green"_. Without any further information, I'd say that you are approaching the problem in the wrong way. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi I've edited my example to more closely show what I want to do, I didn't put that first since I just wanted general guidance so I could work the rest out on my own.

Comment: Don't ask for general guidance on Stack Overflow. SO is for detailed answers, not broad ones.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of is [`tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-tap):

```
def my_method
  do_some_stuff.tap { |return_value| byebug }
end
```

`tap` executes the block (starts byebug) and returns the receiver after the block returns.

Within byebug, you can then examine the local variables via `var local` which shows the current value of `return_value`.

Comment: This is part way there, the problem is that I'd like to be able to inspect the return value, which is why I wanted it to be assigned to a variable